# Using UDF in a DataFrame

Tags: scala, apache-spark, user-defined-functions

I have a dataframe dfmmmIncOther:

```
 dfmmmIncOther=dfmmmIncOther.agg(max("time_res"),min("time_res"),avg("time_res")).withColumn("typestat",lit("IQ_SU5"))
        .withColumnRenamed("max(time_res)","delay max")
        .withColumnRenamed("min(time_res)","delay min")
        .withColumnRenamed("avg(time_res)","delay moy")
```

Type of `time_res` is a minutes

I did a function to convert minutes to hours, then I convert it on `UDF` to use it after:

// convert hours on udf

```
 val convertHours : (Int) => String =(input: Int) => {
      val minutes = input%60
      val hours   = input/60
      "%sh:%sm".format(hours,minutes)
    }

    val udfconvertHours = udf(convertHours)*
```

I changed the variable dfmmmIncOther, to convert minutes to hours:

```
dfmmmIncOther=dfmmmIncOther.withColumn("delaymax",udfconvertHours(col("delay max"))).withColumn("delaymin",udfconvertHours(col("delay min"))).withColumn("delaymoy",udfconvertHours(col("delay moy")))
```

the spark interpreter is return a big exception, I think my fault in syntax but don't know where's exactly.

Some remark from you, I will be appreciate

Comment: can you share the exception as well? can you share the schema or data of `dfmmnIncOther`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the main that you are doing wrong reassigning the variable `dfmmmIncOther`

You can use new variable to store it rather than to reassign it

Here is the simple example

```
import spark.implicits._

//sample data 
val dfmmmIncOther = Seq(120, 122, 12, 68, 123, 435, 234).toDF("time_res")

//create an UDF 
val udfconvertHours = udf((input: Int) => "%sh:%sm".format(input/60,input%60))

//calculate and apply udf
var result = dfmmmIncOther.agg(
  max("time_res").as("max"),
  min("time_res").as("min"),
  avg("time_res").as("avg")
  )
  .withColumn("typestat", lit("IQ_SU5"))
  .withColumn("delaymax",udfconvertHours(col("max")))
  .withColumn("delaymin",udfconvertHours(col("min")))
  .withColumn("delaymoy",udfconvertHours(col("avg")))

result.show(false)
```

Output:

```
+---+---+------------------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
|max|min|avg               |typestat|delaymax|delaymin|delaymoy|
+---+---+------------------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
|435|12 |159.14285714285714|IQ_SU5  |7h:15m  |0h:12m  |2h:39m  |
+---+---+------------------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
```